# Avoiding label identical attributes on duplicate geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry, expression, duplication

The following expression is used to label duplicate geometries avoiding text overlap:

```
array_to_string(
    array_prepend(
        overlay_equals('POINT_LABEL',VALUETEXT),
        "VALUETEXT"
        )
    )
```

Although the function works perfectly and the labels do not appear overlapped (as shown in the screenshot), I would like to solve the problem of repeated labels being displayed. The repetition is happening because all the geometries are being labelled.

I think that a solution could be to group the repeated values for every duplicate geometry, since eliminating duplicate geometries is not a possibility in my project case. Or maybe there is a different solution approach.

- Current result:

  [image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not optimal, but I was only able to find this solution. It would be better to call it a workaround. It may display a different result for your data.

```
array_to_string( 
  array_distinct(
     overlay_nearest('POINT_LABEL', VALUETEXT)
  ),
  delimiter:='\n'
)
```

[image]